# Как правильно организовать открытие окон по кнопкам? (создание и размещение указателей)

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qt-designer

Допустим, у меня имеется окно main, в котором присутствует 10 кнопок, которые открывают 10 разных окон.
Например вот одна кнопка :

```
QAction *actionSelectZap = ui->menuBar->addAction(tr("Выбор записи"));
connect(actionSelectZap,SIGNAL(triggered()),this,SLOT(slotOpenFormChoice()));
```

Как правильно организовать это открытие? в каких местах создавать указатели?
И как в идеале должна выглядеть функция-обработчик? (описание слота?)

Добавлено:
Хочу уточнить, что я, например, могу в обработчике сделать вот так:

```
FormChoice* formchoice= new FormChoice;
formchoice->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose, true);
formchoice->show();
```

И это работает, но мне хочется узнать реально крутые и правильные метода создания такого функционала. Чтобы, например использовались умные указатели а не то, что я предложил.

mainwindow.h:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <memory>
#include "formchoice.h"

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    FormChoice formchoice;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "formchoice.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"


MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    this->setWindowTitle("Observer_demo");

    ui->menuBar->addAction(tr("Выбор записи"), [&]() {
        formchoice.exec();
    });
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

formchoice.h:

```
#ifndef FORMCHOICE_H
#define FORMCHOICE_H

#include <QDialog>

namespace Ui {
class FormChoice;
}

class FormChoice : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit FormChoice(QDialog*parent = 0);
    ~FormChoice();


private:
    Ui::FormChoice *ui;
};

#endif // FORMCHOICE_H
```

formchoice.cpp:

```
#include "formchoice.h"
#include "ui_formchoice.h"
#include <memory>

FormChoice::FormChoice(QDialog*parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::FormChoice)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    this->setWindowTitle("Выбор записи");

}

FormChoice::~FormChoice()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "formchoice.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    qputenv("QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR", "1");
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Эм, вариантов много и я не уверен, что есть какой-то эталон (на самом деле его нет). Но, попробуйте, для начала, например, уйти от макросов SIGNAL SLOT к лямбда-функциям (С++11).

Для примера возьмем конструктор главного окна (используем вот этот метод [addAction](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmenubar.html#addAction-1)):

```
MainWindow() {
    ui->menuBar->addAction(tr("Выбор записи"), this, [&]() {
        FormChoice* formchoice= new FormChoice;
        // Можно перенести этот атрибут в конструктор окна
        formchoice->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose, true);
        formchoice->show();
    });
    ...
    ui->menuBar->addAction(tr("Выбор записи 10"), this, [&]() {
        FormChoice_10* formchoice= new FormChoice_10;
        formchoice->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose, true);
        formchoice->show();
    });
}
```

В этом варианте вам не надо плодить слоты, все реализуется в лямбдах. Умные указатели тут тоже не нужны, потому что ваши окна уничтожаются после закрытия (`Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose`)

Часто окна нужны в модальном режиме и поэтому:

```
ui->menuBar->addAction(tr("Выбор записи"), [&]() {
    FormChoice formchoice;
    formchoice.exec();
});
```

Объект окна (либо наследник `QDialog`, или имеющий метод `exec()` с `QEventLoop` в нем) удалится после завершения работы лямбда-функции

Comment: Этот код не компилируется в QtCreator. Что касается первых двух примеров, то: ошибка: C2661: 'QMenuBar::addAction': no overloaded function takes 2 arguments. 
что касается модального окна: та же, что и в первом случае +  ошибка: C2039: 'exec': is not a member of 'FormChoice' . А так же:  ошибка: C2039: '__this': is not a member of 'FormChoice'

Comment: Добавил код в описание, чтобы можно было воспроизвести

Comment: Поправка: я понял, что exec() есть только у диалога, а был виджет. это я поправил, но осталась проблема с 2 аргументами для QMenuBar::addAction.

Comment: Поправка2: если вы опечатались - забыли вторую скобку после (tr("Выбор записи") , то эта ошибка уходит, но окно не вызывается.

Comment: да, там должен быть аргумент - получатель события. Во вотором примере окно должно быть наследником QDialog, или содержать метод exec()

Comment: Подскажите еще такой момент, пожалуйста. Я вижу в документации сигнатуру addAction(const QString &text, Functor functor), которая как раз подходит для нас. Но вероятно вызывается addAction(const QString &text), т.к. он ругается, что не может принять 2 аргумента. Как это можно вылечить?

Comment: Просто у меня так и не получилось запустить Ваш код. Из-за этой ошибки

Comment: @Artem.rtv какая версия Qt у вас? - у меня Qt 5.15.2 все работает из коробки. Еще в pro-файле должна быть вот такая директива CONFIG += c++11 минимум. addAction работает и с двумя аргументами и с тремя, только что проверил

Comment: 5.8.0. Строчку с конфигом я добавил, да. Странно, конечно. Ну не смотря на это, спасибо большое за представленные методы, это красиво, спасибо!  постараюсь как-то это починить, чтобы заработало

Comment: @Artem.rtv запустил ваш пример - все работает. Попробуйте очистить проект и собрать заново

Comment: я понял наконец. Почему-то мой взор усиленно избегал строчки в документации, где написано, что эта перегрузка появилась с версии 5.11 :)